# How do I select one button on a page which has same classes as all other buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

How do I add event listeners on click to the edit button and make them edit different sections if the classes and HTML code is the same for all edit buttons

```
<div className="top-row">
  <div className="left-header">ABOUT ME</div>
  <div className="right-header">Edit</div>
</div>
<div className="bottom-row">

...

<div className="top-row">
  <div className="left-header">PLEASE UPDATE YOUR LINKS</div>
  <div className="right-header">Edit</div>
</div>
<div className="bottom-row">
```

Screen layout for reference
[image]

`getElementByClassName()` does not seem to work

Comment: you copuld give each button an `id` and select by that with `getElementById()`

Comment: Yes that can be done but the site I'm cloning is doing it without ids, so I was wondering how that is done @JoSSte

Comment: @Ujjwal the method is `getElementsByClassName` with an `s`

Comment: The site you are cloning probably uses a generic component. That generic component gets create for each unique instance (ie [{ title: 'ABOUT ME'}, { title: 'PLEASE UPDATE YOUR LINKS'}]. The generic component would then handle clicks and more without using ids or classes.

Comment: @JoSSte Using id's is easy enough, but bad practice as those approaches create brittle code that doesn't scale well. ID's should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @ScottMarcus so its better to assume that the element with the exact classlist you want or which is the fifth child of the seventh child of root is the right one?

I agree that there are potentially better options I do not agree that they should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @JoSSte Which particular query method you use (based on class, `closest`, `nextElementSibling`, `nth-child`,`parent`, etc.) will vary based on your HTML and your requirements, but in general, yes, ID's should be avoided whenever possible because as the application scales and requirements change (which will always happen), you find that adding a new element means adding a new ID and adding a new ID means altering the code to account for it. Other approaches allow for changing HTML without any changes to the JS.

Comment: @ScottMarcus can you provide a reference? and how does my existing code have to change if I add a new unique ID? adding any new functionality requires you to add to the code, no matter how you do it (with the exception of purely data driven applications)

Comment: @JoSSte Implementing code that works only on uniquely identified elements will no longer work when a new element needs to be added as the new element will have to be accounted for by referencing its new unique ID in the JS. When working with HTML structures that may repeat, but the structure of that HTML doesn't change, you can absolutely implement JS code that will not have to be altered in any way and still pick up on the new element, so the only change in code is the addition of new HTML. The best example of this would be a to-do list.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I do not agree with that - but i get the feeling that we are discussing this while missing the complete picture. It sounds like something we could discuss somewhere else.

Comment: @JoSSte I find it difficult to understand why you say you disagree with factual information. This isn’t my opinion. The more specific code is, the more brittle and less scalable the code is. This is a core tenant of computing that manifests itself in a variety of ways across a variety of architectures and coding frameworks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253073/discussion-between-josste-and-scott-marcus).

Comment: @JoSSte Sorry, but I really have no desire to debate well-known principles and methodologies. If you do the minimal research on this topic, you'll see that this isn't just my (or anyone else's opinion). It's a demonstrable fact.

Comment: @ScottMarcus whcih you keep stating without any references...

Comment: For people finding this in the future: read this gist: https://gist.github.com/arvindpdmn/9fb4c8860bdb9c8d0c7694640965d46e#file-js-done-right-2-md wherein it states that `getElementById()` has a major downfall in that not all elements have Ids and that there are more modern approaches like se `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` and determine what is fact (something that is known to have happened or to exist, especially something for which proof exists, or about which there is information), and what is best practice. Always make informed decisions and don't just trust everything

Comment: @JoSSte While that article you provided bolsters my point of avoiding the use of IDs, but the article does not address what I've been saying which is that the scalability of code that relies on IDs will become more brittle (do you really need a source to be cited here to acknowledge that code that relies on "John" is more brittle than code that relies on say "human"?) and therefore less scalable.  [Using IDs can also cause conflicts with `window` properties](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object).

Comment: @JoSSte Any experienced web developer learns pretty early on that using IDs is an easy way to make code work, but soon thereafter, when the code needs to be scaled up, you learn that relying on IDs has caused the code to be so specific that extending it becomes problematic (how many times have you seen people have problems trying to dynamically generate unique IDs to allow the application to scale?). You're asking for sources to be cited that confirm a best-practice/methodology? Have you ever heard of the principle of "loose-coupling" or "object-oriented programming"? ...

Comment: @JoSSte [Here's a code sample](https://codepen.io/S__MAR/pen/abRvzzq) showing a simple to-do list that doesn't rely on IDs and can accommodate any number of items. How would you write the same functionality with IDs? How would you handle new items being created with a unique ID and making sure that the Remove button removes the correct list item?

Comment: you clearly haven't read my comments in the chat... 
@ScottMarcus Let me take step back:
I agree that using IDs does not scale well.
I agree that there are frameworks and other methods of addressing specific elements.
I agree that there are multiple other methods of working with elements in javascript.
We can possibly agree that those statements are fact

Comment: the second post i made is too long to paste here...

Comment: @JoSSte I have read your comments and directly responded to them. Now you seem to be backtracking and are agreeing with all my points that you previously disagreed with. Anyway, this is exactly what I hoped to avoid (a long back and forth only to arrive at the same obvious conclusion that you have arrived at). Anyway, good luck to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of ways to do this based on element classes, position of the type, based on data attributes etc.

Here are a few examples.

```js
function editLinks(event) {
  console.log("Get that link edited!");
}

function editAbout(event) {
  console.log("Edit About!");
}

function lastHandler(event) {
  console.log("lastHandler woot!");
}

function clickAnotherEventHander(event) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(`We have to: ${this.dataset.type} `);
}

function clickEventHander(event) {
  const action = event.target.dataset.eventAction;
  switch (action) {
    case 'editLinks':
      editLinks(event)
      break;
    case 'editAbout':
      editAbout(event)
      break;
    default:
      console.log(`Sorry, we are out of ${action}.`);
  }
}
const edits = document.querySelector('.container-a').querySelectorAll('.right-header');
edits.forEach(edt => {
  edt.addEventListener('click', clickEventHander, false);
});

const nextup = document.querySelector('.container-b')
  .querySelectorAll('[data-event-action="another"]');
nextup.forEach(edt => {
  edt.addEventListener('click', clickAnotherEventHander, false);
});

const lastly = document.querySelector('.container-b')
  .querySelectorAll('.right-header:nth-last-of-type(1)');
lastly.forEach(edt => {
  console.log('geter done');
  edt.addEventListener('click', lastHandler, false);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  border: double #00FF00 3px;
}

.right-header {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: #FFA500;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.a-row {
  border: solid 1px #0000FF;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-a">
  <div class="a-row top-row">
    <div class="left-header">ABOUT ME</div>
    <div class="right-header" data-event-action="editLinks">Edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-row">
    <div class="left-header">Send Freddy home</div>
    <div class="right-header" data-event-action="sendFreddy">Edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-row">
    <div class="left-header">Fish for dinner</div>
    <div class="right-header" data-event-action="fish">Edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-row bottom-row">
    <div class="left-header">PLEASE UPDATE YOUR LINKS</div>
    <div class="right-header" data-event-action="editAbout">Edit</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container container-b">
  <div class="a-row top-row">
    <div class="left-header">ABOUT ME</div>
    <div class="right-header" data-event-action="another" data-type="Get beer!">Edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-row">
    <div class="left-header">What? Click and see!</div>
    <div class="right-header" data-event-action="another" data-type="walleye">Edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-row">
    <div class="left-header">Fish for dinner</div>
    <div class="right-header" data-event-action="another" data-type="bass">Edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-row bottom-row">
    <div class="left-header">I do nothing!</div>
    <div class="right-header" data-event-action="whocares">Edit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use a selector that is position based to qualify it.

Also, your HTML is incorrect, you should be using `class` not `className`. `className` is used in JavaScript to access a list of all the classes applied to an element. In HTML, you just use the `class` attribute.

See comments below:

```js
// Set up a single event handler on a common ancestor of 
// the elements you wish to handle
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", function (event){
  // Determine if the event originated at an element you care about
  if(event.target.classList.contains("right-header")){
    // Handle the event based on the text of the
    // clicked element's immediate previous element sibling
    switch (event.target.closest("div.top-row").querySelector("div.left-header").textContent.toLowerCase()) {
        case "about me":
          console.log("You clicked the About Me edit.");
          break;
        case "email":
          console.log("You clicked the Email edit.");
          break;
        case "links":
          console.log("You clicked the Links edit.");
          break;
     }
  }
});
```

```css
.right-header {
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #808080;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top-row">
    <div class="left-header">ABOUT ME</div>
    <div class="right-header">Edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="top-row">
    <div class="left-header">EMAIL</div>
    <div class="right-header">Edit</div>
  </div>
  <div class="top-row">
    <div class="left-header">LINKS</div>
    <div class="right-header">Edit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-edison-hii8rb?file=/index.html

you can use querySelectorAll to catch all elements if this class, and use forEach to iterate them.

I found an error, you use class as className, this is used in React, in HTML we use only class, because this you can't get with getElementsByClassName function.

```
<div class="top-row">
  <div class="left-header">ABOUT ME</div>
  <div class="right-header">Edit</div>
</div>
<div />

<div class="top-row">
  <div class="left-header">PLEASE UPDATE YOUR LINKS</div>
  <div class="right-header">Edit</div>
</div>
<div />

<script>
  const editBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".right-header");
  editBtn.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer leaves out the most important part, which is handling different element clicks differently. Your answer just finds all the elements and performs the same operation on all of them.

Comment: Also, please don't post answer code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time, making your answer meaningless. Always post your code right here in your answer. You can create a Stack Snippet that will execute right here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, because you're asking for help re-creating the functionality of a site based on its HTML, but you tagged this question with `React`, so if you're just using HTML to code this site, then @JoSSte is right, you can just use unique ids to select the elements in question. You could also use `getElementsByClassName` and write individual `addEventListener` callbacks for each item in the resultant array. That would look something like this:

```
let editButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("right-header");

editButtons[0].addEventListener("click", (event) => {Enter function here});
```

If you're looking to execute different actions for each Edit button using React, but the site that you're trying to clone isn't utilizing unique ids for each one, then it's likely they're probably using `props` to pass the information for each action into a component that's being called multiple times.

For example, you could do something like this in your components:

```js
//INSIDE PARENT COMPONENT: 

  const editAboutMe = () => {
   { Desired functionality here }
  }    

  return (
    <>
      <MenuItem title="ABOUT ME" edit={editAboutMe}/>
    </>
  ) 

//INSIDE CHILD COMPONENT:
  
  return (
    <>
      <div>{title}<div>
      <div onClick={edit}>EDIT</div>
    </>
  )
```

Code is a bit choppy, but hopefully that helps!